# Wordpress not using edited image

Tags: media-library, editor, single, images, cropping

I have uploaded a picture to media library and cropped the image in wordpress editor but when selecting the edited image http://mariehelenesund.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Kicki-e1447542665309.jpg (which shows in media library after being edited) wp instead displays an old image http://mariehelenesund.se/wp-content/uploads/2015/11/Kicki-1000x750.jpg
. I have registered image size, see below

```
    add_image_size( 'index-thumb', 1000, 1000 );
```

Why is not the edited image shown?

Comment: Try using a plugin called regenerate thumbnails and see if that helps.

Comment: I am not sure where does the `....-e144...` file name comes from, could u elaborate a bit where are you seeing it?

Answer (score 0):

Did yoy check the image height is it more than 1000px.  Because if the height is less than ur specified one it will use the current size of the image.

Comment: Hi, it was less than a 1000px, but why is not the original image edited by the editor?

Comment: Did you try to regenerate you thumbnails?

Comment: If your original image is very small than how it will edit it by giving larger width and height.  If you upload a big resolution image.  You can see the editor is working.